# How to use sql to ignore a part of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SQL table with 500,000 records in orders table.
The sql have been used for past 5 years and every year there are about 100,000 records  added on  the  database.
The table has about 30 fields , one of the fields is "OrderDate"
The query needs only  records for the last few  months, maximum past 12 months.
so all the records before that are just useless and slow down all the query.

query is slow, and takes 3-4sec, same query was almost immediate few years ago.
i have to load and print all fields columns at once.
Can i make the SQL ignore and not look through part of records, suppose records with OrderDate before 2013, or first 400,000 records or ignore certain part of the records without deleting them?

Comment: Filtering data using where clause

Comment: I suggest you to first index the column and also you could create a view to be easier to select your records

Comment: You write as if there s only ever one query for this table? True or unlikely? Or do ALL query always need to ignore older records?

Comment: What are your indexes on the table? Primary key? Other kinds of queries? Other factors that might effect performance, like increased load? Total size of the DB relative to available server memory?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any indexes on the table, and when you add the proper indexes, your speed problem will go away and you won't have to worry about this "ignore a part of the table" stuff.

Comment: I am already using a view, and using where. 99% of the time the older records should be ignored. I have order_id Primary key. total db is 6GB and server memory is 8GB ram. I do not use indexes but for this table i do need all the columns of the view that i use-will indexing solve my prob?

Comment: A  500,000 record table without understanding indexes is asking for trouble. Indexes do not affect the columns that you can select. Please do some research on indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have two options:

- Creating a new table which is identical to the old one and insert there the rows that you want to ignore, then, delete those same rows from the original table. This solution is good in the case that those rows are "useless" to every query (and if it's viable, you can update other queries that make use of those rows).
- Index the column.

Comment: "This solution is good in the case that those rows are "useless" to every query." Well, if that were really the case on could just delete the useless rows without concern for a second table. *gasp* I know--who throws away even "useless" data these days?

Comment: Another solution is create a table just for keeping history. Then maybe use a job to insert the records you won't use and delete from "working" table

Comment: Karl, maybe it's useless for the daily tasks of the office but probably not for another department. Either way, you could get fired for deleting old data (specially if it's from the order table)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use of table partitioning, but we don't know what type of SQL you're using so we don't know if it supports it. Add a tag for the version of SQL (SQL Server? Oracle?)

Comment: I have added, its 2008 R2

Comment: If it's enterprise edition then you can use table partitioning. Which is kind of what you're asking for.

Comment: version 10.50.1600.1 i dont know if thats an enterprise.

Comment: No that's the version. Search on 'finding sql server edition'. You probably don't have enterprise - it's expensive.

Comment: Web Edition (64-bit)  - this means that i will not be able to partition?

Comment: No. So your next option for performance improvements is indexes or rewriting queries. Do you have any indexes created?

Comment: No, i havnt used indexing because i need all the columns , and want to ignore from the first records.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Indexing will improve SELECT performance without limiting the columns that you can SELECT